# function call in do while loop only execute once.

Tags: c

I had a program to check user input and make sure it's only integer and not character. In my `main` function,  `do while` loop only executes once when the input is incorrect. But I want it to keep it executing until the user enter a valid input. My **doAgain()** function is to ask if the user want to *Try again or not*. **The problem is** with **doAgain()** function. It only executes once if leave it in the `if` statement. Everything works fine except this glitch. However, when i remove it, the loop keep executing until the user enter valid input like i wanted it to, but then **doAgain()** function would be useless

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

/* get boundary */

```
 char* getBoundary(char str[]){
    int i;
    char c;

     str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) // The loop stop running after the second time
    {
        str = (char *) realloc(str, sizeof(char) + i);
        str[i] = c;
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

/* check for valid string */

```
 int checkStr(const char *check)

{
    unsigned i;
    size_t len = strlen(check);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(isalpha(check[i]))
        {
            printf("Invalid integer formatt!!!");
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

/* Ask if do again */

```
int doAgain(void)
{
    char ans, c;

    do {
        printf("Do you want to try again?: ");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);

        switch (ans) 
        {   
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                return (ans == 'y') || (ans == 'Y') ? 1 : 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid answer!!! answer 'y' and 'Y' or 'n' and 'N' only\n");
                do { /* flush input stream */
                    c = getchar();
                }while (c != '\n'); 
        }   
    }while (1);
}
```

/* Main */

```
int main(void)
{

    char *l_boundRow;
    l_boundRow = NULL;


    do {
        printf("Enter lower bound row: ");
        l_boundRow  = getBoundary(l_boundRow);

        if (!checkStr(l_boundRow) && doAgain())  // problem start here, it works if I remove doAgain() function
            continue; // if the string is invalid, the program asks user if they want to try again
        else
            break;
    }while (1);

    free(l_boundRow);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The break after the return is unreachable code.  You could simplify the code by do `return 1;` after `case 'y': case 'Y':` and `return 0;` after `case 'n': case 'N':`.  However, both those points are tangential to your current problem.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Revised answer

The immediate problem is that when `doAgain()` exits with `y` or `n`, it doesn't read the newline after those characters, so when it re-enters `getBoundary()`, the first character it reads is whatever was after the `y` or `n` which was probably a newline, which terminates the input line.  You need to gobble the rest of the line on a valid input as well as on the invalid ones.

This code mostly works — it is leak free, too (at least under my casual testing).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* getBoundary(void);
int checkStr(const char *check);
int doAgain(void);

/* get boundary */

char* getBoundary(void)
{
    int i;
    int c;
    char *str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; i++)
    {
        str = (char *) realloc(str, 2 + i);
        str[i] = c;
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
    return str;
}

/* check for valid string */

int checkStr(const char *check)
{
    unsigned i;
    size_t len = strlen(check);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(check[i]))
        {
            printf("Invalid integer format (%s)!!!\n", check);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

static int gobble(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
    return c;
}

/* Ask if do again */

int doAgain(void)
{
    char ans;
    int c;

    do {
        printf("Do you want to try again?: ");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);

        switch (ans)
        {
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                c = gobble();
                return 1;
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                c = gobble();
                return 0;
            default:
            {
                printf("Invalid answer!!! answer 'y' and 'Y' or 'n' and 'N' only\n");
                c = gobble();
                if (c == EOF)
                {
                    printf("EOF detected\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (1);
}

/* Main */

int main(void)
{
    char *l_boundRow;
    l_boundRow = NULL;

    do {
        printf("Enter lower bound row: ");
        l_boundRow  = getBoundary();

        if (checkStr(l_boundRow))
            break;
        if (!doAgain())
            break;
        free(l_boundRow);
    }while (1);

    printf("Final bound row: %s\n", l_boundRow);
    free(l_boundRow);
    return 0;
}
```

If you select not to try again after an invalid input, the last invalid value is printed as the 'Final bound row'.  You can easily hack the code to avoid that problem.

Incidentally, when I first compiled your code, I only got 3 warnings from it under my default stringent options — because I demand prototypes before (non-static) function definitions.  That's extremely good; well done.  Few people write code that's posted on SO that passes that level of scrutiny with as few complaints.

If it were my code, I would have few if any `do … while` loops (none in this code).  They are occasionally useful, but occasionally is the operative term.  Generally, it is best to use a top-testing `while` loop, or an explicit `for` loop.

---

#### Original answer

<sup>*A real problem, but not the one immediately causing trouble.*</sup>

In the code in `getBoundary()`, you first allocate one character.  Then, in the body of the loop, you reallocate `i + 1` characters.  On the first iteration, you reallocate 1 byte; then 2, etc.  And then when you exit the loop, you write one beyond the last character that was allocated, which leads to undefined behaviour.  You need to use `i + 2` as the size to reallocate.  (There are those who'd rail against you for using `sizeof(char)` since that is guaranteed to be `1`.)

That is probably the source of your trouble; writing beyond the end of an allocated buffer can easily lead to crashes.

If you ran the code under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), it would tell you about this mistake.

Separately, it is not a good idea to allocate one more byte each time around the loop.  It would be better to allocate, say, 20 bytes (big enough to hold any 64-bit integer value), or to double the size on each iteration when you need more space.  It isn't going to be time critical in this context, but it can become a problem in bigger programs.

Note too that your `checkstr()` function only detects alpha characters; punctuation and control characters will also not convert to an integer.  You should check that each character is a digit (`isdigit(check[i])`), and you might have to worry about plain `char` being signed — so `isdigit((unsigned char)check[i])` is better still.  Similar comments apply to the other `isuvwxyz()` functions.

In `doAgain()`, you should use `int c;` instead of `char c;` and you should check for EOF as well as newline.  If you detect EOF, the answer is 'no' and you should return that.

Also, in your `getBoundary()` function again, you have:

> ```
> str = (char *) realloc(str, sizeof(char) + i);
> ```

There are those who would castigate you for the cast; I am not of the mindset that does that.  But be aware that you will get criticism for doing so from many people who answer questions on C at SO.

More significantly, you should not write the `realloc()` code this way.  The idiom:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);
```

leaks memory if the allocation fails.  You've just had the only pointer to the memory wiped out with NULL, even though `realloc()` promises that it did not free the old memory.  You should use:

```
void *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);
if (new_ptr == NULL)
    …handle out of memory condition…ptr is still valid!
ptr = new_ptr;
```

You should also always check that memory allocations succeed.  If they fail, you end up dereferencing a null pointer, which leads to crashes.

Comment: I adjusted everything you recommended but I still don't understand why the loop would terminate and only execute once? Did i put **continue** statement in the wrong place???

Comment: See the update.  I think your condition was partly wrong; but you also had another problem with the `doAgain()` function not eating the newline after the `y` or `n` response, so the `getBoundary()` function was immediately reading a newline and terminating.